# How to send a message in Thunderbird that is in your outbox?

Tags: email, thunderbird, email-client

I'm composing some emails up now but I don't wish to send them just yet, so I am going to `File > Send Later` to send them to the *outbox*.

Now I opened the message in the *outbox* but I see no option to send it? The only option I see is by going to `File > Send unsent messages`; but what if I only want to send a specific one?

I know I can *right click* the message and select `Edit as New Message`, but that doesn't seem like the right way to do it?

Comment: I need to use `Edit as New Message` even when I save a message in `Drafts`, so I think you have the solution, even if it doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Send individual messages from outbox**

As you discovered, the Outbox control is all or nothing for messages that are already there.  From [Mozilla](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Outbox#Sending_mail_in_the_Outbox):

> You cannot select which messages in the Outbox will be sent. You can only send them all. If you want to send some messages in the Outbox but not others, you could move the others to another folder temporarily.

So that's a workaround if you have a lot of messages there and want to send a portion of them.

If you want to send an individual message, the Send button is accessed in the message edit window.  You need to reopen the message in the message editor to send it.  You can do that with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd> or from the menu: `Message | Edit as New Message`.

**Enhancing control over Send Later**

In case you aren't aware of it, there is an add-on called `Send Later` by Jonathan Kamens (go to Get Add-ons in the Add-ons Manager, and put "Send Later" in the search box).  The website is [here](https://blog.kamens.us/send-later/).  It might potentially allow you to avoid the problem by giving you very detailed control over scheduling sending.  So you could do things like work on messages and schedule them all to be sent at a specific time and date or after a certain time period has elapsed.  This screen shot will give you an idea of the control:

[image]

Note that Thunderbird must be running at the scheduled send time.  Otherwise, sending will wait until Thunderbird runs again.  There are, however, some Internet services that can be used in conjunction with Thunderbird to send messages even if Thunderbird isn't running.  The Mozilla link at the top includes some suggestions.